# How stable is ROS for long-term operations?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

We are considering using ROS for an industrial robot application. The application requires that we need to run the robot for more than 100 days continuously without errors (software crash, etc) and human intervention. The use of ROS with its topics/services/etc. will considerably reduce development time for our application, but how will ROS perform for long term testing?

**Anyone who has experience with long-term testing of systems running on ROS (e.g., > 10 days continuous operations)?**

(Note: the "Office Marathon" by Willow Garage is perhaps one example of relatively long-term testing, but that was still "only" for 30 hours operation)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46681/how-stable-is-ros-for-long-term-operations?/) by [Roba](https://answers.ros.org/users/3458/roba/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2012-10-24

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) on 2012-10-24**:
I think that the answers to this question will depend heavily on the particular packages (and libraries) being used, whether nodes are listed as required, and what hardware is being used. You should probably specify ones that you may be interested in..

**Comment by [Roba](https://answers.ros.org/users/3458/roba/) on 2012-10-24**:
Thanks for the comment trinighost. We are planning on mostly writing our own nodes/packages, but we are considering making use of ROS-industrial, the OROCOS toolchain for realtime operations, and the BFL. HW is to be decided on. My main concern is the main ROS functions such as message passing.

**Comment by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) on 2012-10-24**:
If you're worried about the core services and want to know how robost ROS is in an industrial env I would suggest taking a cut and branching from there. So you can throughtly test what you need to work. Then move forward with that. Factor back in updates as you need them.

**Comment by [thebyohazard](https://answers.ros.org/users/1483/thebyohazard/) on 2012-10-24**:
You might have a look at [Baxter](http://www.ros.org/news/2012/09/rethink-ros.html) from rethink robotics.  It's pretty early in its life, but they're marketing it, so I'd be surprised if it wasn't fairly reliable. (I have no experience with it btw.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

At Willow we've done long duration experiments 10+ days: [Related Blog post](http://www.willowgarage.com/blog/2011/01/03/1389-km)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-10-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm assuming that you've already joined the [googlegroup](http://groups.google.com/group/swri-ros-pkg-dev)

And I'd also suggest taking a look at the [multimaster SIG](http://ros.org/wiki/sig/Multimaster).

Personally I haven't used any of these stacks/packages/toolchains.. but I've done just under 10 days at a time with the same roscore (diamondback from debs with custom nodes creating and processing data) and "simple" message passing (std_msgs and sensor_msgs).  My aim at that time wasn't to explore reliability, but it probably will be changing soon.

Others can also comment, but I do not think message passing is an issue at this stage, the challenge is going to surround what your rosgraph does with the messages that are being passed. How well is your activity specified, does your code meet specs, do you have an accurate spec for the code/packages that you depend on etc..

---

Originally posted by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) with karma: 2022 on 2012-10-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1